# How do I set the contents of an Excel cell equal to a string variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am formatting some data I received. I have several hundred names of students in Column A, and for some strange reason there is a random * placed randomly throughout the names. I want to programmatically remove all * characters from all names.

```
 For x = 2 To 300

        Dim strStudent as String

        //how do i set contents of cell to string strStudent

        strStudent = Replace(strStudent, "*", "") //replace * with nothing

 Next
```

My question is, how do I set the contents of the cell we are looping through to the strStudent variable?

Comment: isn't this the same question as your previous question?

Comment: Notice that my last question was answered differently.  We did not set the cell's contents equal to the string variable, and that is the part that I want to understand how to do.

Comment: What column is this in?

Comment: Nothing's changed, still in Column A like the last question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim strStudent As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 2 To 300
        strStudent = Replace(.Range("A" & x).Value, "*", "") '//replace * with nothing
        .Range("A" & x).Value = strStudent 
    Next
End With
```

Alternatively you don't need a variable

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 2 To 300
        .Range("A" & x).Value = Replace(.Range("A" & x).Value, "*", "") 
    Next
End With
```